# Turn a String to a 24 hour time format, using moment.Js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to format a String into a 24 hour format using moment JS at the moment I am not getting the expected output, the below explains it in more detail:

How I am coverting

```
 var testFormat = moment("9:00","HH:mm:ss");
```

I was hoping this would output:

09:00:00 (24 Hour format)

But for some reason is does not convert just the date, this is outputing the following:

```
1471507200000
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using it wrong. You can provide a format as the second argument to moment. So in your case it would be:

```
var myMoment = moment("9:00","H:mm");
```

To get the `moment`. Now you can format it the way you want:

```
myMoment.format("HH:mm:ss");
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/85kac0xx/)

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!

Comment: Could the same be applied to dates?

Comment: Sure. You only need to parse the date with the correct format (like in the first line of my answer), then format it however you want. You'll find all formating options in moments docs! @DarrenW

Answer (score 1):

Below mentioned statement will give 12 hrs format

```
moment("13:15:00", "h:mm:ss").format("hh:mm A");
```